# How do I ignore certain elements when comparing XML?

Tags: java, xml, junit, xmlunit

I have an XML message like so:

```
<root>
  <elementA>something</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
</root>
```

I want to compare a message of this type produced by a method under test to an expected message, but I don't care about `elementA`.  So, I'd like the above message to be considered equal to:

```
<root>
  <elementA>something different</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
</root>
```

I'm using the latest version of [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

I'm imagining that the answer involves creating a custom `DifferenceListener`; I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's something ready to use out there.

Suggestions that use a library other than XMLUnit are welcome.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Things have changed a lot for [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/2.1.1/index.html) since this question was answered.

You can now easily ignore a node when using a `DiffBuilder`:

```
final Diff documentDiff = DiffBuilder
            .compare(expectedSource)
            .withTest(actualSource)
            .withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals(someName))
            .build();
```

If you then call `documentDiff.hasDifferences()` nodes added to filter will be ignored.

Comment: Looks good - but how to use ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier with DiffBuilder ??? to allow different order of xml elements?

Answer (score 41):

I wound up implementing a `DifferenceListener` that takes a list of node names (with namespaces) to ignore textual differences for:

```
public class IgnoreNamedElementsDifferenceListener implements DifferenceListener {
    private Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>();

    public IgnoreNamedElementsDifferenceListener(String ... elementNames) {
        for (String name : elementNames) {
            blackList.add(name);
        }
    }

    public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
        if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.TEXT_VALUE_ID) {
            if (blackList.contains(difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getParentNode().getNodeName())) {
                return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
            }
        }

        return DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
    }

    public void skippedComparison(Node node, Node node1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it's this complex - disappointing if xmlunit does not have something built in for ignoring specific elements?

Comment: This solution is quite old now. Apparently the new xmlunit programming model uses [ComparisonListener](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/2.4.0/org/xmlunit/diff/ComparisonListener.html), not DifferenceListener.

Answer (score 9):

I would use XSLT and the [identity transform](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) to filter out elements I want to ignore, and compare the results.

See [XSL: how to copy a tree, but removing some nodes ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137563/xsl-how-to-copy-a-tree-but-removing-some-nodes/1137628#1137628) earlier on SO.

Answer (score 6):

You can now try `${xmlunit.ignore}` in XMLUnit 2.6.0 (add dependency xmlunit-placeholders). Sample code is as below.

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder
    .compare(expectedXML)
    .withTest(actualXML)
    .withDifferenceEvaluator(new PlaceholderDifferenceEvaluator())
    .build();
```

Expected XML:

```
<root>
  <elementA>${xmlunit.ignore}</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
</root>
```

Actual XML:

```
<root>
  <elementA>anything</elementA>
  <elementB>something else</elementB>
  <elementC>yet another thing</elementC>
</root>
```

Do notice that currently the ${xmlunit.ignore} only supports text node and attribute value ignorance, as can be seen from the [unit tests](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/blob/master/xmlunit-placeholders/src/test/java/org/xmlunit/placeholder/PlaceholderDifferenceEvaluatorTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it simple, to **ignore nodes** irrespective of length of how many nodes you want to ignore or if you dont know **how many number of nodes you want to ignore**, follow these simple steps

*This is just a XMLdiff method with two xml's as a string*

```
public static void XMLdiff(String XML1, String XML2){
               
 //nodes you wanted to ignore
        String[] ignoreNodes = {"nodeX", "nodeY", "nodeZ"};
      
//testnode(node,ignoreNodes) is handled below for finding and ignoring multiple nodes
        final Diff documentDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(XML1)
                                  .withTest(XML2)
                                  .withNodeFilter(node->testnode(node,ignoreNodes))
                                  .build();
}

private static boolean testnode(Node node, String[] name) {

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

            if (node.getNodeName().toString().equals(name[i])) {
                return false;
            }
            if (name.length == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**add dependencies or jar from this link https://www.xmlunit.org/**