# Testing XML with XMLUnit with a variable value

Tags: java, xmlunit

I have some XML which I am testing, which has set as one of it's elements the date and time.  This obviously will change every time the test is run.

Is there a way to compare the XML and have this node value ignored, or just checked with a regular expression or something.

The XML I am testing is as follows:

```
<xml-fragment>
    <core:date xmlns:core="http://www.company.com/commerce/common/V1/core">2010-06-24T21:41:22.456+01:00</core:date>
    <core:serviceName xmlns:core="http://www.company.com/commerce/common/V1/core">calculateNextAndFuturePayments
    </core:serviceName>
    <core:ackRequired xmlns:core="http://www.company.com/commerce/common/V1/core">false</core:ackRequired>
    <v1:viewingCardNumber xmlns:v1="http://www.company.com/commerce/calculateNextAndFuturePayment/V1">405536053
    </v1:viewingCardNumber>
</xml-fragment>
```

I would like to check that the initial element (core:date) is in the date format, but the values are irrelevant for equality purposes.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're generating the XML in your code, but using something like `new Date()` to get the current date/time? I suggest you inject a clock as a dependency, just like any other dependency. That way you can control what time your code thinks is "now" and have predictable XML to test.

Injecting a clock has proved really useful in my experience - and incredibly easy to do. I'd recommend having a `Clock` interface with implementations along the lines of `SystemClock` and (for production) and `FakeClock` (for testing).

Whether you express the current time in millis, `Date` or (my preference) something from Joda Time, it's a good way of isolating the dependency.