# Ignore few children for comparison when comparing xml documents with XMLUnit

Tags: xml, comparison, xmlunit

Is it possible to ignore a few children in elements when comparing XML documents with XMLUnit? I want to ignore any empty text nodes in the element when comparing them.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Comment: 1) override the differenceFound in DifferenceListener but then it ignores the other differences in the element.

2) set the XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true). this does not seem to work for compareXML(Document control, Document test)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use this listener:

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DifferenceConstants;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DifferenceListener;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class IgnoreChildrenOfNamedElementsDifferenceListener implements DifferenceListener {
    public IgnoreChildrenOfNamedElementsDifferenceListener() {}

    public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
        if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID ||
                difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH_ID ||
                difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND_ID) {
                return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
            }
        }    
        return DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) {}
}
```

Then you can use it in following way:

```
Diff diff = new Diff(expectedDoc, obtainedDoc);
diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreChildrenOfNamedElementsDifferenceListener("TestDateTime"));
```