# XMLUnit - Ignoring 'id' attribute in comparison

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I am currently working with XMLUnit and I am wondering if there is way to configure it to ignore **only** the `id` attribute of the tags I want to compare.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna try to implement my own [DifferenceListener](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/DifferenceListener.html) to handle this need (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml)). Gonna post the result soon. It seems to work, gonna post the implementation tomorrow.

Comment: could you send example, please?

Comment: You should take a look at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml) it's pretty much like the listener I implemented.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is quite simple. You can configure your `DifferenceEngine` to handle `ATTR_VALUE` differences. Write custom difference listener class which implements DifferenceListener:

```
class IgnoreIDsDifferenceListener implements DifferenceListener {
    private static final int[] IGNORE_VALUES = new int[] {
            DifferenceConstants.ATTR_VALUE.getId(),
    };

    private boolean isIgnoredDifference(Difference difference) {
        int differenceId = difference.getId();
        for (int i=0; i < IGNORE_VALUES.length; ++i) {
            if (differenceId == IGNORE_VALUES[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
        if (isIgnoredDifference(difference)) {
            return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
        } else {
            return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
        }
    }

    public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) {
    }
}
```

The required thing here is to check whether the attribute name is "id". Standard Java DOM functionality could help. But I prefer to do this by the means of regular expressions:

```
String controlNode = difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().toString();
controlNode .matches("^id=\".*\"")
```

P.S. See also: http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Difference.html