# Ignore attributes XML Unit

Tags: java, xmlunit

I am comparing XML files with XMLUnit and was wondering and if an element does not exist in one of the files then all subsequent elements generate the alert of: [not identical] Expected sequence of child nodes 'X' but was 'Y'.  I am wondering if there is an easy way to prevent these alerts from being generated in the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want different tags to be compared, you can easily add this line

```
XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(Boolean.FALSE);
```

But if you want to ignore a tag you must override `DifferenceListener`, here a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml) that may help you.