# How do I ignore a dynamic timestamp using XML unit?

Tags: java, xml

I'm comparing an xml i receive back from an api for my tests in Java. I have the expected response in my project file the section I would like to ignore in the xml is this.

```
<timestamp>2016-12-12T15:19:31+0000</timestamp>
```

I already have my assertion in place. Does xml unit have an ignore that is similar to json unit which I've also used in this block of tests? Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml

Comment: I did see this one I was hoping someone could elaborate a bit more I will give it another go thanks.

Comment: May be you can add your findings or what has been already tried and outstanding issue that is being faced. This will help someone to be able to revert back quicker.