# How to ignore some value in spring-ws-test

Tags: java, spring-ws

I follow [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html) to create test for testing my endpoint. Problem is that in my response I am returning current time which I dont want to test. Is there some way how to ignore some value like:             ${IGNORE}

Answer (score 2):

The default `ResponseMatchers` class supplied with Spring-WS uses the `PayloadDiffMatcher` in order to compare the given and expected payload. The compare is done using an [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/) `Diff`. You could extend the [PayloadDiffMatcher](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring-ws-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/test/support/matcher/PayloadDiffMatcher.java) (or implement your own custom `ResponseMatcher`) so that it allows specifying a filter for your current time element as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442237/4201470).

Another option is to use the `xpath()` `ResponseMatcher` and only check parts of the returned response, ignoring the time element.