# How to compare two XML files ignoring specific tags in java JDK7

Tags: java, xmlunit-2

I am trying to compare the two XML files where certain tags has to be ignored. How can this be achieved? Since I am using JDK 7, lambda expressions cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda expression really only is syntactic sugar for an anonymous inner class. The example of [Java: How do I ignore certain elements when comparing XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241593/java-how-do-i-ignore-certain-elements-when-comparing-xml)

```
.withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals(someName))
```

is really just

```
import org.xmlunit.util.Predicate;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

.withNodeFilter(new Predicate<Node>() {
    public boolean test(Node node) {
        return !node.getNodeName().equals(someName);
    }
})
```

No need for Java8.