# XMLUNIT How do I ignore multiple elements when comparing XML?

Tags: java, xmlunit-2

I am able to compare 2 xml files using XMLUNIT 2.5 DiffBuilder. I want to ignore certain elements using withNodeFilter. But the withNodeFilter accepts only 1 element. Is there a way to ignore more that one element for comparison.

```
DiffBuilder.compare(DocB)
.withTest(docA)
.withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals("metadata")) // need to include more element tags to ignore
.build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use logic operators, for example,

```
.withNodeFilter(node -> !(node.getNodeName().equals("metadata") ||
                          node.getNodeName().equals("comment"))
```

This will match all nodes which are not `metadata` or `comment`.

Answer (score 0):

I think **TheZeus121**'s solution looks good if there are **one or two** nodes, but if you want to add **more than 10 nodes to ignore** in xml comparison, then I think this tradition way of keep on adding nodes using '||' or '&&'is not a right approach. So, just I had modified for such kind of approach, please have a look in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68099435/13451711